# Find specific column range and line using VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript

I have a txt file that I only need to read the first line, but only want values from column 64-70 from line 1. How do I do this in vbscript? I have looked at several ways to do this but can't get exactly what I'm looking for. Please help.

Comment: Please provide some details on what you have looked at / tried. Also would help to show a mockup of what your text file looks like.

Answer (score 2):

For the reading characters from the line, use `Mid(source_str, 64, 6)`. -- 6 is the length from character 64 to 70.

As for reading the first line from the text file, you will need to set up a loop to read each line until the end of the file, parse them into an array of strings, then process only the 1st.

Or, since you only need the first line, just run `fsoStream.ReadLine()` once.

So in your case:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("filename.txt")

'This only reads the first line of the file. 
'To read any others, we would need a loop.
line = file.ReadLine() 

thisStr = Mid(line,64,6)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this worked perfectly.. I now need one to read the last line in the file.. Can you provide an example of the loop you are referring to to pull the last line?  Thank you again

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The loop I'm referring to is `While Not EOF(file) line = file.ReadLine() Wend`. If you overwrite the `line` variable in the loop, or process it in the while-wend loop every time, you should be able to detect the last line as the line you are left with when the loop exits. Just make sure you `Dim line` before entering the loop, so it doesn't get deallocated when the loop exits.

Comment: Of course, this might cause problems, as you'll be dealing with filestream integers. `Do While file.AtEndOfStream <> True line = file.ReadLine Loop` is an alternative example Microsoft gives [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7se9d4f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) that will probably work a little better.